# How to skip over CORS in angularjs (no access to server side)

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get a JSON from my angularjs (v1) client website. My code:

```
$http.get('https://usernamexx:passxx@backend.sigfox.com/api/devicetypes');
```

I am getting:

```
Failed to load https://backend.sigfox.com/api/devicetypes: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

That domain is not mine and I can't enable CORS on that backend.

If I go to https://usernamexx:passxx@backend.sigfox.com/api/devicetypes in any browser I get the JSON without any CORS problem. If I use Postman app I get the JSON without problems too.

How can I deal with this issue in angularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to omit this restriction purely with JavaScript on client side. You can however temporarly disable this security mechanism by installing plugins for some of the browsers ie. Chrome that will automatically add *Acess-Control-Allow-Origin:** to all responses to requests that browser made. This plugin for Chorme is available 
[here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en). Obviously won't expect each client to install this plugin just to make your application work in their browser

There are 3 ways to resolve CORS problems permanently:

1. Create a backend middleware that would automatically add relevant headers to each request you make to an external domain (Possible)
2. Add server side code that will return header *Acess-Control-Allow-Origin*  in the response to request you make with your application (Not possible in your case)
3. Put your application in the same domain as the external domain (Perhaps possible, CORS won't be applied)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If you decide to use NodeJS the https://github.com/expressjs/cors might speed up the process for you

Answer (score 0):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

This is the link to an extension in chrome that adds to response

```
Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```